# when i setroot page my menu button is hidding in ionic 3

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3

when i click home in a menu, there is used [this.navCtrl.setRoot(homepage);].
in that page it does not display menu button.

actullay  this is my home page:

[image]

when i set setroot for homepage it shows like this

[image]

Html code in header:

```
<button ion-button menuToggle style="margin-top: 10px;" >
      <ion-icon name="menu" style="color: white;"></ion-icon>
   </button>
```

menu code:

```
<ion-menu [content]="mycontent" type="overlay"> <ion-content>
    <ion-list class="nobottomborder"> 

        <ion-item  (click)="dashboard()">
            <ion-icon ios="ios-home" md="md-home" class="sidebaricon"></ion-icon>
           Home
        </ion-item>

      <ion-item (click)="addcart()">
          <ion-icon ios="ios-cart" md="md-cart" class="sidebaricon"></ion-icon>
         My Cart
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item (click)="orders()">
          <ion-icon ios="ios-list-box" md="md-list-box" class="sidebaricon"></ion-icon>
         My Orders
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item (click)="logout()">
          <ion-icon ios="ios-exit" md="md-exit" class="sidebaricon"></ion-icon>
        Logout 
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="powered">
        Powered by
        <ion-row>
        <img src="assets/imgs/logo.png" alt="logo">
      </ion-row>
      </ion-item>

      </ion-list> </ion-content> 
    </ion-menu>
```

Comment: show me home html page

Answer (score 0):

I have added like below and it is working great(I have homepage root initial) :

Home:

```
  <ion-navbar>
    <button menuToggle ion-button>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

Comment: the above code working. but when i setroot for homepage only it hiding

Comment: do you mean you are re setting root?